# Wix to remove previous version that was installed with Bootstrapper from control panel

Tags: installation, wix

I've got "ABC 10.1" program version installed on computer allready and I would like to remove it on each newer ABC.msi installation (for example when ABC 10.2 is going to be installed).

So far I've used a BOOTSTRAPPER to install new versions and it worked like a charm (the previous version was uninstalled and removed from the control panel and newest was appearing in the control panel).

Right now I would like to use ABC.msi for installation and to not use the BOOTSTRAPPER, but when I use ABC.msi installer the previous one is not being removed from the control panel and I have two "ABCs" 10.1 and 10.2 versions in the control panel.

**How can I remove ABC previous version that was installed by BOOTSTRAPPER during newest ABC.msi installation (and avoid duplicating ABC in Control Panel)?**

Bundle.wxs

```
<Bundle 
Name="$(var.ProductName)" 
Version="$(var.ShowVersion)" 
Manufacturer="ABC" 
UpgradeCode="33312c8d-64f1-4a04-a98e-4aa692de6aaf"
IconSourceFile="$(var.BaseDir)\Setup\UI\ABC.ico" 
Condition="((VersionNT = v6.1 AND ServicePackLevel &gt;= 1) OR (VersionNT &gt; v6.1)) AND (WixBundleInstalled = 0)">
<BootstrapperApplicationRef Id="WixStandardBootstrapperApplication.RtfLicense">
  <bal:WixStandardBootstrapperApplication 
    LicenseFile="$(var.BaseDir)\Setup\UI\License.rtf" 
    LogoFile="$(var.BaseDir)\Setup\UI\OticonAppIcon.png"
    SuppressOptionsUI="yes"
    ShowVersion="yes"/>
</BootstrapperApplicationRef>

    <Chain>
  <!-- Install .Net 4.6.1  -->
  <PackageGroupRef Id='NetFx461Redist'/>

  <!-- my packages to install -->
  <PackageGroupRef Id="InstallerPackages" />        
</Chain>


</Bundle>
<Fragment>
<PackageGroup Id ="InstallerPackages" >
  <MsiPackage SourceFile="$(var.OutDir)\ABC.MSI" />
  <MsiPackage SourceFile="$(var.OutDir)\DatabaseInstallerABC.msi" />
</PackageGroup>
</Fragment>
```

productABC.wxs (the file that is creating ABC.msi) is as following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?include .\defines.wxi ?>
<Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi"     xmlns:netfx="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/NetFxExtension"      xmlns:fire="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/FirewallExtension"      xmlns:util="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/UtilExtension">
  <Product Id="$(var.ProductCode)" 
  Codepage="1252" Language="1033" 
  Manufacturer="ABC" Name="$(var.ProductName)" 
  UpgradeCode="{3338CE6B-D733-41AF-830B-DCAFE2E0CD58}" 
  Version="$(var.ProductVersion)">
 <Package Id="*" 
 Compressed="yes" 
InstallerVersion="300" 
Languages="1033" 
Manufacturer="ABC" 
Platform="x86" />

<Media Id="1" 
Cabinet="media1.cab" 
EmbedCab="yes" />

----some directories and components----

<MajorUpgrade
  Schedule="afterInstallInitialize"
  DowngradeErrorMessage="A later version of [ProductName] is already installed. Setup will now exit." 
  AllowSameVersionUpgrades="yes"/>

<InstallExecuteSequence>
  <LaunchConditions After="AppSearch" />
  <Custom Action="SetTargetDir" Before="CostFinalize"></Custom>
  <Custom Action="SaveTargetDir" After="InstallValidate"></Custom>
</InstallExecuteSequence>

<WixVariable Id="WixUILicenseRtf" Value="$(var.BaseDir)\Setup\UI\License.rtf" />
<WixVariable Id="WixUIBannerBmp" Value="$(var.BaseDir)\Setup\UI\bannrbmp.bmp" />
<WixVariable Id="WixUIDialogBmp" Value="$(var.BaseDir)\Setup\UI\ABCbackground.bmp" />

</Product>
</Wix>
```

Comment: Your MSI UpgradeCode needs to be the same between both MSI versions, whether they were installed using a bootstrapper or on their own.

Comment: UpgradeCode is the same in the new msi and in the current msi (I've checked this with the orca software). I don't know if bootstraper makes something extra

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generic answer: The wix bootstrapper is what writes the entry in the Control Panel for your "ABC 10.1" release. In order to remove that, your 10.2 release will need to have a custom action tell the previous bundle to uninstall itself ("previous-cached-bundle.exe /silent /uninstall" or something similar). Now, whether you tell the old bundle to remove itself first, or you allow your MSI to upgrade first is up to your own requirements.